# rewrite domain to url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have main domain for example  domain.com and i need rewrite another  to url for example if  domain not domain.com and domain is http://www.yyaa.com/say  rewrite it to 
http://domain.com/index.php?p=say

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)  http://domain.tld/dashboard/$1   [P,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `RewriteCond` that checks if the used domain name is not equal to `domain.com`, before doing the redirect like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*)  http://domain.com/index.php?p=$1   [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I need get get variable like otherdomain.com/32223 need to use 3223 in file like index.php?p=32223

Comment: @user533178: The part after the / (in your example, the `say` bit) is fetched by the first argument of the RewriteRule, the `(.*)` part. Then, it's used in the rewrite by using the `$1` variable. Try reading up on the docs at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html , which explains these things.

Comment: I add my example for formatting only I need code to check if domain name equal say.com rewrite it to URL

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an `R=303` instead of `R=301` if you don't want the redirect to be permanent.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303
versus
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301